# Copy folder contents using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to copy the contents of certain folders to another folder using VBScript.

The goal is to enumerate a user's AD groups and then copy specific folder content based on those groups.

I have code, which is currently not working.

```
Dim Group,User,objFSO,objFolder,source,target,StrDomain

StrDomain = "domain.local"
FolderBase = "\\domain.local\netlogon\workgrps\icons"
Set net = CreateObject("wscript.network")
Struser = net.username
target = "\\fs1\users\"&net.username&"\Desktop\AppIcons\"

DispUserInWhichGroup()

Function DispUserInWhichGroup()

On Error Resume Next

Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set User = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomain & "/" & strUser & ",user")

For Each Group In User.Groups

source = FolderBase & Group.name

Set objFolder = GetFolder(source)

For Each file in objFolder.Files
objFSO.CopyFile source &"\"& file.name, target&"\"&file.name
Next

Next

End Function
```

This has been cobbled together from various sources, and I'm sure most of it is right, I just can't get it working completely.

Any assistance would be great.

Cheers.

Comment: By "not working properly" what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Nothing. I don't get any errors. I can get some info from using wscript.echo to check the folder paths, but I can't get the file copy happening. There are files in the folders, but nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

```
On Error Resume Next
```

line from your function and then you will see any errors that are happening.

**EDIT**: I think you need to specify an object for GetFolder.

```
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(source)
```

Comment: Great. Thankyou. Now I'm getting a type mismatch error for GetFolder. At least I can figure out waht's happening now.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the second \ in the copy statement

```
For Each file in objFolder.Files
   objFSO.CopyFile source & "\" & file.name, target & file.name
Next
```

Also you could use the file objects copy method like this

```
For Each file in objFolder.Files
   file.Copy target & file.name
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it to work. I tried both. I can't even get it to echo the file name within the loop using wscript.echo(file.name) which makes me think I have bigger issues. I wish I had some errors being thrown, at least then I'd have something to go on. There are definitely files in the folders, I'm really not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The destination folder does not have to exist, but it must be specified:

C:\Z to C:\A\Z will work, but C:\Z to C:\A will not work.

The folder that the new folder will be in must exist:

C:\A must exist, but C:\A\Z does not have to.

The trailing slashes should be omitted:

C:\Z to C:\A\Z will work but C:\Z\ to C:\A\Z\ will not work.